# Angular 4: Access constants in in HTML of components

Tags: angular

I have created a class where I have defined properties as follows:-

```
export class MyConstants{
public static readonly NAME:string:"SIDD";
}
```

I can access the value as MyConstants.NAME in "component.ts" file but if I try to use the same in HTML of the component file, I am not able to do that.

I don't want to create an instance of the above class and then use the same in HTML file. Is there any way to access "MyConstants" class in HTML part of the component.

thanks in advance.
Sidd

Answer (score 5):

**No** you cannot, You have to inject in the class's constructor and use them as you would normally use any property.

Anyhow you can do the following using a getter,

```
Export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public static readonly NAME:string:"SIDD";

  get name() {
    return AppComponent.NAME;
  }

}
```

// in HTML

```
<div>{{ name| json }}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. This I wanted to avoid but seems, there is no way, other than that.